# Executing an SQL command with EntityManager

Tags: java, sql-server, entitymanager, hibernate-native-query

Is it possible to run an SQL script that doesn't return a resultSet or is not an INSERT or UPDATE type of script?

I'm trying the following:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DECLARE @max int;\n" +
        "SELECT @max = MAX(customer_number)+1\n" +
        "FROM organisation\n" +
        "\n" +
        "exec('ALTER SEQUENCE organisation_customer_number_seq RESTART WITH ' + @max)");
```

...but of course that just creates the query, how to execute it? I can only find getters for different types of resultSets and executeUpdate method for Query. How to just run that query I created above to restart a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the methods you see in `Query` actually execute the query, e.g [Query.getResultList](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) :

> **getResultList()**
>
> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped
>   List.

```
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
```

UPDATE : in your case the query ends up being an `ALTER` so as you figured it out, the relevant method will be `executeUpdate()` which returns no list or value, but the number of affected rows.

> **int executeUpdate()**
>
> Execute an update or delete statement.

```
int altered =  q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case it throws an exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: Could you try with `getSingleResult()` instead ?

Comment: That didn't work either. q.executeUpdate(); worked :)

Comment: Oh yes I didn't get that your final query will be an `ALTER` not a `SELECT` .

Comment: You can modify your answer and I'll set it as correct